# Passing Parameters from Mod_rewrite to PHP with a front end comprising of just HTML & JS

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mod-rewrite

I have a web application, the front end is HTML & JavaScript/jQuery and The back is PHP.

It was using ugly URL's like so, host/app/Page.php?userid=1.... Ugly!
So with a little MOD_REWRITE it will now serve the urls as url/page/1/

```
RewriteRule    ^page/([0-9]+)/?$    host/app/page.php?userid=$1    [NC,L]
```

Next it originally did simple jQuery GET request to the PHP files to get the dynamic data.

```
var params = A JS function to get all paramters after the ? in URL
var userid = params.id;

$.getJSON('host/app/page_code.php',{'userid':userid}, function(data) {
    var blah = data.blah;
});
```

Now after using MOD_REWRITE I now have no nice way of getting the front end to the parameters, only in a page/1 format. Looping though and getting each parameter between the slashes just doesn't feel like the right way to do it.

So I hit Google and it seems that sending the parameters from MOD_REWRITE seems like the way to do it. So my questions are, how is this possible, how is it done?

How do I get the parameters from the URL with MOD_REWRITE, send those to the PHP back-end, then return a response to the front end with JSON?

edit: The problem I have is I need to pass Parameters from JS to a PHP back end then get a response. I originally got these parameters from the URL with JS, then passed them into the GET request, I would then get a response from the PHP depending on the Parameter sent. However now I have used mod_rewrite on the URL I can not see the parameters on the front end to catch in the traditional ?a=b&c=d format. it now looks like /b/d To get these in JS I can only do this by looping through and getting each parameter between the slashes. Doesn't seem right to do it like this. I need to actually some how get the parameters to the PHP code in a separate page from the front end. Then pass it back to the front end with the response from the PHP code so I have lets say the users id. I don't want any php in the front end file as to keep it all separated. There must be a way to get the parameters from the url to the PHP code in a different file, then send back a response to the front end HTML&JS with the usersid. I'm new to this whole MOD_REWRITE for clean urls, and it's confusing the hell out of me!

Comment: @imsiso Wont that just pass it to the front end page though? I need it to go from mod_rewrite, to the back-end PHP then to the front end in JSON.

Comment: Did an edit with more info, hope that makes more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a reverse router with javascript in which given a URL, it returns the parameters.

Example (really bad one, just to give you an idea) [on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dgCfb/)

Drawbacks: you will have to copy the routings from `.htacces` file to Javascript. Everytime something changes in that file, you will have to change in Javascript too.

Edit:

## Another approaches

- Do all the routing processing in PHP, not even using `.htaccess` and then retrieve data for routing in JSON format. You'd access this from an Ajax request

Example:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'reverse_routing.php', 
    type: 'json', 
    data: {
        url: window.location.pathname 
    }, 
    function(params) {  
       // Do your stuff here...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use a post method with http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Example from jquery.

```
$( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log( $(this).serialize() );
});
```

An idea to pass the data in a PHP sense.

```
data = $( "form" ).serialize();
$.post("serverside.php", data, function(returnData)
{
    $("divid").html(returndata)
}
```